# Why doesn't this animate?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

http://plnkr.co/edit/k9W3AVDJS3spQXuUnHmF

I am trying to animate using the `$animate` service with the `animate.css` library, but I can't seem to get it right. The blue block works because it's using the animate.css class, how can I make it `$animate.leave` with another css class from the library. Second, the red block isn't entering and using the `.ng-enter` classes. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works: http://plnkr.co/edit/lVijrARDS4Nu9VPSAUl3?p=preview

First, this is why your example is not working:

1. Blue box animates because it uses Animate.css classes directly and it doesn't use Angular.js animation pipeline at all.
2. Red box doesn't animate, because animation is set to run on initial application start. Angular prevents animations to run on initial application setup to prevent performance issues that may be caused by a lot of elements animate at the same time.

You need to do the following changes to enable red box animation:

```
$timeout(fn)

function fn() {
  redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block"></div>')
  $animate.enter(redBlockElement, bodyElement).then(function() {
    $animate.leave(redBlockElement)
  })
}
```

I simply used `$timeout` service to prevent DOM enter for 0 second, so it is (technically) run after application start, so animations are going to run.

But, you also need to add transition rule into `.ng-enter` itself, not into body, so I also add this line to CSS to make animations work:

```
.block.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

3. Now we are able to run our applications, but we didn't integrate `animate.css` into Angular.js yet. I change animation related style to this:

   .red.ng-enter {
     -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1s;
     animation: fadeInRight 1s;
   }
   .red.ng-leave {
     -webkit-animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
     animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
   }

Now I am using fade effect from `animate.css`!

4. One last thing, enter animations work, but exists do not work. In Angular 1.3.x you need to manually start a digest cycle after animation complete, or UI changes will not be reflected until something else triggers a digest cycle. That's why we need to add `$rootScope.$apply();

In Angular 1.4.x you don't need to do that.

So the final JS:

```
$timeout(myFn);
function myFn() {
  bodyElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'))

  redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block"></div>')
  $animate.enter(redBlockElement, bodyElement).then(function() {
    $animate.leave(redBlockElement);
    $rootScope.$apply();
  })
}
```

Final CSS:

```
.red.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1s;
  animation: fadeInRight 1s;
}
.red.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
  animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
}
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lVijrARDS4Nu9VPSAUl3?p=preview

Comment: Ahh, I should have tried the ``$apply``. I was really surprised that it didn't work. I think I'll try on 1.4 to see if anything breaks. Thanks!

Comment: Can I enter a $compiled element? I need to apply a certain scope to the element

Comment: @Strawberry sure, it shouldn't be a problem. If you need I can prepare another plunker, this time compiling html with a scope, and assigning that scope to a controller in a directive.

Comment: I made another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689787/why-cant-i-animate-a-compiled-directive. I can make it as best answer.